# Is there a way to use both auth0-spring-security-api and java-jwt in the same project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, auth0

I'm trying to use auth0 and JWT in my Spring Boot project. I have imported these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I also use JwtWebSecurityConfigurer to configure spring security.

If I use only `auth0-spring-security-api`, `JwtWebSecurityConfigurer` works correctly and checks my token. But I can't use the JWT class that is contained in `java-jwt` artifact.

If I import both dependencies in pom, it stops working and when Spring security checks my token, I get an error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.Verification.withIssuer(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/auth0/jwt/interfaces/Verification;

Also, I know that `java-jwt` library is a dependency of `auth0-spring-security-api`, I think that there's a sort of collision with two libraries. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! If anyone has this problem, the solution is:
Check your pom.xml and the pom of auth0-spring-security-api. The java-jwt dependency imported from auth0-spring-security-api must be the same of java-jwt in your pom.